# putting a set of images into a cluster.

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, cluster-analysis, face-recognition

I want to group images into several clusters.

I am working on an automatic face tagging system. To make tagging easier, I want to put visually similar images in the same cluster. That is, my input will be sets of face images. I need to extract features from each of these faces, compare the feature vectors and put similar faces in a cluster. However, i don't know what feature extraction technique to use. So far, based on mathworks, I've tried SURFFeatures, HarrisFeatures, MSERFeatures but none of them are giving me proper feature vectors that i can use for comparsion. What feature extraction technique should i use to accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean by "similar faces" ?

Comment: Yes.  What is your measure of "similar-ness"?

Comment: I want to put images of the same person in one cluster. Similar faces is a misleading term. I want to put all face images belonging to a person in one cluster. Hence, i need a measure to compare two faces and group them together if they are the same person.